# Can you install lamp onto a network hdd?

Tags: linux, webserver, lamp, nas

I have a WD MyBook Live Network-Attached-Storage device.  I want to install a home lamp server  on it, just for testing purposes of building a website.  I need to have MySQL as well.  Is this an option?

Comment: This a standalone networked-drive or attached to a computer?  Needs to have something running an os to do this - some comp acting as server, the hdd is just an install location at that point.   Performance is not so good, but for just testing...

Comment: It's standalone, I want to install Linux on it and remote into it, do I still need a computer connected to it ?

Comment: Like an nas-type thing. That usually pretty much is a computer itself. Although you'll need to check specs and all to see if you can support a full install of Linux/apache etc.  they often have some customized pared-down os running. What is the brand/model?

Comment: It's a western digital my book live

Answer (score 0):

You can *install* things on an external hard drive, but you cannot *run* them there.  You can only run them on the computer to which you've attached the external hard drive.  In other words, you need a computer to run a LAMP stack, and if you have a computer, it doesn't matter if the computer is using an internal or external hard drive.  The only difference between an internal hard drive and an external drive is that external hard drives are often (but not always) slower.

Comment: Ok think you I have a better understanding now

Comment: @Willis-Blackburn: Most of the newer NAS drives are running media-servers and the like for streaming videos, etc.  The newest mybook live is already running some version of Debian/linux.   So it's basically a computer already.

Comment: Neil--Yes, I know that.  But the OP didn't mention NAS in his question;  he just said it was an "external hdd."

Comment: @WillisBlackburn roger that, I had the benefit of several Q&A commments back and forth to clarify things a bit.  Perhaps the original question should be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some forums specifically dedicated to your NAS drive. As I noted in the comment above, the newest version of the Mybook is running a fully-featured Debian build.

For example:
http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/mybook-live

Looks like it has some tips and instructions on doing exactly what you want.  One thing to watch out for is it's not a standard intel-based-architecture 32/64-bit cpu, it's more like a customized SOC/ARM architecture.  So the availability of tools and build procedures are going to be more limited.

EDIT: I also wanted to add that it might save a lot of headaches to just rent the economy linux hosting plan at godaddy (or wherever) for some personal web space.  I did this years ago and have used it for tons of things like this.  But if you're the kind of person who likes this sort of project (hacking your electronics to put to work, etc) then go for it.  But sometimes this stuff is not for the faint of heart.